# MVC 4 and dataTables: checkbox entry returns null ViewModel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

What I'm trying to do is that first I need to display a list of Members that I need to add to a group. Then the user would then click on each checkbox for each row of Members that the user chooses. My code is already running. The problem is, when I applied the jquery.dataTable (which renders perfectly too) it doesn't seem to return all the necessary data when some of the Members are hidden away (via next page or search). Everything works fine when I click show 100, thus showing every hidden data, of the dataTable.

my ViewModel

```
public class ChooseMembersEditorViewModel
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

    public ChooseMembersEditorViewModel()
    {
        this.Selected = false;
        this.Id = "";
    }
}
```

which is inside another ViewModel

```
public class AddMemberViewModel
{
    public List<Group> Group{ get; set; }
    public List<ChooseMembersEditorViewModel> LGMembers { get; set; }

    public AddLifegroupMemberViewModel()
    {
        this.Group= new List<Group>();
        this.LGMembers = new List<ChooseMembersEditorViewModel>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> getSelectedIds()
    {
        var getSelected = (from members in this.LGMembers
                           where members.Selected
                           select members.Id); //returns error here saying value cannot be null
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Count {0}", getSelected.Count()));
        return getSelected;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

When I check 1 of the values and hit Add Member,  I get a value must not be null from inside the getSelectedIds Linq

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

This is how I list all the members. The SubmitSelectedMembers basically gets all the members whose id's where checked and adds them to the database.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult AddLifegroupMembers(int id)
    {
        var model = new AddLifegroupMemberViewModel();

        Lifegroup lifegroup = db.Lifegroup.Find(id);

        int leaderAge = GetAge(lifegroup.LGLeader.User.Birthday);
        ViewBag.Age = leaderAge;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", lifegroup.LGName.ToString()));

        var nonMembers = from u in db.Users
                         where !(from lgm in db.LGMember
                                 select lgm.UserID).Contains(u.Id) //should not be part of any Lifegroup
                                 &&
                               !(from l in db.Lifegroup
                                 where l.LifegroupID.Equals(id)
                                 select l.LGLeader.UserID).Contains(u.Id) //should not include leader of said group
                         select u;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of LG: {0}", model.Lifegroup.Count()));

        foreach (var user in nonMembers)
        {
            int age = GetAge(user.Birthday);

            var editorViewModel = new ChooseMembersEditorViewModel()
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.FirstName, user.LastName),
                Selected = false,
                Age = age.ToString(),
                Sex = user.Sex
            };

            model.LGMembers.Add(editorViewModel);
        }
        model.Lifegroup.Add(lifegroup);

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitSelectedMembers(AddLifegroupMemberViewModel model)
    {
        var getSelected = (from members in model.LGMembers
                           where members.Selected
                           select members.Id);

        List<string> _selected = new List<string>();
        foreach (var selected in getSelected)
        {
            _selected.Add(selected);
        }

        //var selectedIds = model.getSelectedIds();
        var lifegroupID = model.Lifegroup[0].LifegroupID;

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Lifegroup ID: {0}", model.Lifegroup.LifegroupID));

        var selectedUsers = from u in db.Users
                            //where selectedIds.Contains(u.Id
                            where _selected.Contains(u.Id)
                            select u;

        foreach (var users in selectedUsers)
        {
            var idManager = new IdentityManager();
            idManager.AddUserToRole(users.Id, "LifegroupMember");

            var lgmember = new LGMember()
            {
                LifegroupID = lifegroupID,
                UserID = users.Id,
                DateJoined = DateTime.Now
            };

            /* 
             *  Insert Code to insert part of Lifegroup to GrowthMileStone                
             */

            db.LGMember.Add(lgmember);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ViewLifegroups");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the objects before inserting them in the LGMembers-list. This isn't happening in the code above.

Comment: Hi @badaBoom, I'm not really sure what you mean by initializing the object. I'm already able to submit and call the entities properly. The only problem is that dataTable seems to hide the elements when I search, or turn the page prior execution. Thus some values indicate that they're null.

Comment: How do you insert objects in LGMembers? How does the code look like? Can you share it as well? Are the objects in the list LGMembers instantiated? Make sure the objects of type ChooseMembersEditorViewModel are instantiated.

Comment: @Dominic did you check this out? Don't forget to reply.

Comment: Hi @badaBoom, sorry for the reply. Please check edit for the insert Objects. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for checkbox entry null ViewModel is that, filtering or paging cuts your binding View to ViewModel. Because binding can not see an element that is not shown at the time of post. Although not very good solution, if someone wants to solve problem in this way the solutionn for this problem can be removing filtering or paging before submit. Example for solution is placed in form submit

```
table.search('').columns().search('').draw()
```

or

```
table.fnFilter("");
var oSettings = table.fnSettings();
table._iDisplayLength = -1;
table.fnDraw();
```